# How to translate this code into imacros?

Tags: html, imacros

I've Inspect Element for my stuck code imacros here:

```
<div style="" class="ember-view liquid-container" id="ember1587">
      <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px;" class="ember-view liquid-child" id="ember1757">
         <textarea class="ember-view ember-text-area" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Deskripsi Produk dan #hashtag" maxlength="3000" id="ember1764"><!----></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="lf-fade ember-view liquid-container" id="ember1592">
   <!---->
</div>
```

how to translate it in imacros code? the id=ember15** is dynamic.

i have tried this code, but it can't write in the textarea field.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:.st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;}<SP>Deskripsi<SP>P*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* CONTENT=blablabla
```

Thankssss

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code, it will identify the text area whose id starts with 'ember'

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:ember* CONTENT=blablabla
```

Comment: i try it but error....RuntimeError: element TEXTAREA specified by ID:ember* was not found, line 21 (Error code: -921)

Comment: What's the error?.. othewise go with the xpath, identify the xpath of that text area and try the code like below..
` TAG XPATH= "//select[@id="billing:country_id"]" CONTENT=xyz`